# Authentication methods missing when connecting to ArcGIS FeatureSevice in QGIS 3.14 (Pi)

Tags: qgis, authentication

I am trying to connect to an ArcGIS-10.3 FeatureService in QGIS 3.14 (Pi) recently installed.
In the connection details window, I have the URL but in the "Authentication" part, in "configuration", only "no authentication" is available. There is no drop down options available. I need an OAuth2 authentication (the plugin is installed - I checked in the Authentication window in Settings - options - authentication, installed plugins).

Comment: From the "Basic" tab you can add the basic auth credentials. I do not see other options in my QGIS 3.14 but I do not have OAuth2 plugin.

Comment: thank you, see my answer below. that basic tab is compulsory and then the right authentication method can be selected when back in the "configuration" window

Answer (score 1):

thanks @user30184 for your answer. You are right, I had to do that Basic authentication step first before I could be taken to this screen where then, OAuth2 authentication becomes available and a token file needs to be uploaded (that was provided to me by the colleagues whose ARCGIS server I wanted to access). successful connection now !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If QGIS is giving right information, OAuth2 does not support ESRI Feature server. However, EsriToken should be supported but I do not see how to use it in the connection wizard.

[image]